# How to make a conditional reference to a text label

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

I would like to make a conditional reference to an optional label in my latex document, see the Minimum Working Example below. Hence, IF the label exists somewhere in the document, THEN a reference will be made, some other place in the document, to that label. I am using the "etool" package, but I am not sure if any of the commands there are usefull for my purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Method}
...the method is based on Anderson et. al 2012,
% CONDITIONAL FUNCTION 
% IF \label{sec-appendix} EXISTS THEN:
{a summary of which is given in Appendix \ref{sec-appendix}.}
% ELSE
{not explained here.}
% END OF CONDITIONAL FUNCTION

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\label{sec-appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can exploit the fact that `\label{xyz}` defines `\r@xyz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iflabelexists}[3]{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{#3}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Method}
...the method is based on Anderson et. al 2012,
\iflabelexists{sec-appendix}
  {a summary of which is given in Appendix~\ref{sec-appendix}.}
  {not explained here.}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\label{sec-appendix}

\end{document}
```

Of course this stabilizes after a couple of runs. If you add `\end{document}` before `\appendix` you'll see.

With `etoolbox` it's simpler, but essentially equivalent:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\iflabelexists}[3]{\ifcsundef{r@#1}{#3}{#2}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution  looks very promissing, I will test it immediately : )

Comment: Hi again..I have encountered one potential problem with the code you suggested. If there is any \ref{sec-appendix} above the \iflabelexists line, then your code interpret this as if the label exists, that is, that `\label{sec-appendix}` exists, when I add `\end{document}` before `\appendix`.

Comment: @EspenDonali Fixed.