# How to test if a label exists

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have tried to follow [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111311/how-to-make-a-conditional-reference-to-a-text-label) but I cannot get it to work. My question is: **How do print a text based on if a reference exists or not?**

I have tried the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse} 

...

\NewDocumentCommand\calledName{m}{%
    \ifcsundef{r@KN:#1}{\ref{FN:#1}}{\ref{KN:#1}}%
}
```

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for not telling.

Comment: And `xparse` of course...

Comment: If the label is FN:#1 or KN:#1, why are you looking for r@#! instead of r@FN:#1 or r@KN:#1?

Comment: Yes :) \usepackage{xparse}

Comment: What do you expect here actually? Your check for  `r@foo` will check whether the label named `foo` exists, but calling either `\ref{FN:#1}` or `\ref{KN:#1}` is useless if `FN:foo` or `KN:foo` are not defined labels

Comment: All the comments wouldn't be necessary if you provided a MWE. [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I think OP wants to know if there exists a reference to a particular label, not whether the label itself exists.

Comment: That was the fist error I had. I should of course check for r@KN:#1 and not r@#1.
I am trying to make sure that if ref{KN:#1} returns ??, then print ref{FN:#1}.

Comment: ref{FN:#1} will always be available as long as #1 is correct. However, sometimes ref{KN:#1} fits better in the text.

Comment: @FireFly3000: Why should `FN:#1` be always available? It's only there if the corresponding label has been defined (or a fake definition of `r@FN:#1` is done)

Comment: @FireFly3000 What's the question? Your code does what it's expected to do.

Comment: The question was the error I had in the test of the reference. It has been found and corrected now so every thing works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a way with `\@ifundefined` and using `latex.ltx` core features.

If the label `KN:#1` is undefined, a reference to `FN:#1` is used (or at least tried to do so.

Another way would use `\getrefnumber` etc. by `refcount` package.

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\calledName[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@KN:#1}{%
    \ref{FN:#1}%
  }{%
    \ref{KN:#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Foo} \label{KN:foostuffwrong}

\section{OtherFoo} \label{FN:foostuff}


\calledName{foostuff}
\calledName{stuff}

\calledName{foostuff}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this method better as it doesn't need a new package :)

Comment: Is there a similar trick for bibitem keys (the one referred to by `\cite` )?