# Conditional cross references (\in and \at) in ConTeXt?

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, context

I am currently in the process of writing a comprehensive theoretical manual for my students. To make it easier to compile texts of varying difficulties for different groups of students, I also make heavy use of **modes**: These enable me to, say, exclude chapters that are intended for second-year-students from PDFs for first-year-students.

To make reading easier, I'm also using a lot of cross references (`\in` and `\at`). Unfortunately, that results in a problem, when a section that I'm referencing is excluded during compilation: Obviously, instead of the reference, the final PDF now shows something like *"see chapter ??"*.

I would like to prevent that. Ideally, I would like to set up a new command that shows the full text of the reference only when the reference exists and is being included. Is that possible?

To make clearer what I'm talking about, here's a MWE (the advanced section might be excluded by compiling with `context --mode=firstyear ...`):

```
\defineblock[advanced]

\startmodeset
  [firstyear]  {\hideblocks[advanced]}
  [secondyear] {\keepblocks[advanced]}
  [default]    {\keepblocks[advanced]}
\stopmodeset

\def\condin#1#2{%
  % the text specified by #1 should be hidden,
  % when the reference #2 does not exist.
}


\starttext

\chapter{Testing Conditional Cross References}


\beginadvanced

\section[sec:advanced]{Advanced Section}

\input{knuth}

\endadvanced


\section[sec:intermediate]{Intermediate Section}

\input{knuth}


\section[sec:beginner]{Beginner Section}

This section explains the topic in beginner's terms
and refers to another chapter for more advanced details:
Please see \in{section}[sec:advanced] for more details.

This whole sentence should be excluded from the PDF,
when the references sec:advanced does not exist.

\stoptext
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired output when mode `firstyear` is enabled? Simply omit the reference:`Please see for more details.` or omit the complete line?

Comment: Does `\doifreferencefoundelse` do what you want?. The other option is to redefine `\dummyreference` to something other than `??`.

Comment: Yes, the intended output would be to omit the complete line, which is why I would probably define a new command, like `\condin{sentence}{reference}`. I didn't know that `\doifreferencefoundelse` exists, I will need to experiment with that. Thank you!

Comment: I now tried `\doifreferencefoundelse`... what a pity that it's not documented too well. But it does exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! Would you like to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I added a short answer. It will be great if you could add the command to the wiki page that I linked in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't find the link to the wiki page that you mentioned... did you include it in your answer?

Comment: Yes. If you click on the `\doif...else` part. I'll include it here also: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Branches_and_Decisions

Comment: Ah, yes, I found the link. Thanks. Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to edit that wiki page, so I added an additional answer here showing the full code that I'm now using. If you find that interesting, maybe you'd like to add that to the wiki?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if a label exists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319437/how-to-test-if-a-label-exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConTeXt provides a command `\doifreferenceelse` (which is a synonym for `\doifelsereference`), which has the following syntax:

```
\doifreferenceelse{name}{yes branch}{no branch}
```

This is similar to the other [`\doif...else`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Branches_and_Decisions) macros.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, anybody is looking for a solution to a similar problem, I'm posting the code that I am using here.

First of all, thanks to @Aditya, who made me aware of the command `\doifreferencefoundelse`: This was the last building block that I needed. In a nutshell, I defined a new command `\condref` like this:

```
\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}

  function userdata.findreference(str)
    _, _, inreference = string.find(str, "\\in[^%[]*%[([^%]]+)%]")
    _, _, atreference = string.find(str, "\\at[^%[]*%[([^%]]+)%]")
    if inreference == nil then
      context(atreference)
    else
      context(inreference)
    end
  end
\stopluacode

\def\condref#1{%
  \doifreferencefoundelse{\ctxlua{userdata.findreference([[#1]])}}
    {#1}
    {}
}
```

This command calls some Lua code to extract the exact cross reference from argument #1 (as specified by `\in{...}[...]` or `\at{...}[...]`). Then `\doifreferencefoundelse` checks, whether the cross reference exists: If it does, the full code from argument #1 is included; if the cross reference is missing, however, the text is deleted (i.e. nothing is included). (This is the first time I'm writing Lua code, so I'd be happy, if somebody could help me make the code more efficient. E.g. I'm not sure, if there's an *or* construction available (like `(in|at)`)?)

I can now use the command like this:

```
She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled
‘ORANGE MARMALADE’ \condref{\footnote{For more information about Orange
Marmelade, please refer to \in{section}[sec:marmalade].}}, but to her
great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for
fear of killing somebody, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards
as she fell past it.
```

If the section that's referenced by `sec:marmalade` exists, the whole footnote is included; if it doesn't (in my case this could happen due to the section being excluded by a compilation mode) the footnote is left out.

Hope that helps.