# Referencing Optional Labels in an Omnibusable Book

Tags: cross-referencing, books, book-design

I have a book on math in several parts

- Arithmetic
- Algebra
- Linear Algebra
- Etc.

I don't necessarily want to wait until all the parts are done to publish some of the parts, then I want to be able to publish an omnibus version  once several parts are complete.

My problem is with \ref, it is not smart enough to handle the use case of a multipart document where some labels may disappear.  I need a command where I can optionally include some reference depending on whether the label was foud during compilation.

e.g

```
\label{optional}
\autoreference{optional}{because of Theorem}
```

Should produce

because of Theorem (optional.theorem.number)

If the label was found in compilation, and nothing otherwise.

Comment: you could process each part as a separate document and use `xr` package to `\ref` labels in external documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional cross references (\in and \at) in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403509/conditional-cross-references-in-and-at-in-context)

Comment: Close voters: This question is not about ConTeXt, so the possible duplicate linked too is none, in my point of view. It's a duplicate for other reasons, it i.e. regarding @DavidCarlisle's comment about `xr`