# Sorting Contents of Macro (Not Literal)

Tags: indexing, sorting, makeindex, keywords

In [How to sort an alphanumeric list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list) , there is a nice and short sort facility, which I am reproducing here:

```
%% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% #1 - comparator
% #2 - token list to sort
\newcommand\sort[2]{%
        \ifstrempty{#2}
        {}% else
        {%
                \sort@begin#1{}#2\sort@s\sort@begin
        }%
}

% helpers
\def\sort@s{\sort@s}
\def\ifsort@s#1{%
        \ifx\sort@s#1%
                \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
                \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
}

% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - smallest token so far
% #4 - rest of the list
\def\sort@begin#1#2#3#4\sort@begin{%
        \ifsort@s{#4}
        {%
                \sortend{#3}%
                \sort#1{#2}%
        }% else
        {%
                \sort@go#1{#2}{#3}#4\sort@go
        }%
}

% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - smallest token so far
% #4 - token under consideration
% #5 - rest of the list
\def\sort@go#1#2#3#4#5\sort@go{%
        #1{#3}{#4}{\sort@output#1{#2}{#5}}%
}
% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - rest of the list
% #4 - smaller of the two tokens
% #5 - larger of the two tokens
\def\sort@output#1#2#3#4#5{%
        \ifsort@s{#3}
        {%
                \sortoutput{#4}%
                \sort#1{#2{#5}}%
        }% else
        {%
                \sort@begin#1{#2{#5}}{#4}#3\sort@begin
        }%
}

\def\sort@numlt#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{#1}<{#2}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@numgt#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{#1}>{#2}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@alpha#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}}<{0}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand*\sortnumlt{\sort\sort@numlt}
\newcommand*\sortnumgt{\sort\sort@numgt}
\newcommand*\sortalpha{\sort\sort@alpha}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\sortoutput[1]{#1 $\rightarrow$ }
\newcommand*\sortend[1]{#1. $\leftarrow$ }
```

I stuck the above into a `sort.sty` file, and now I am trying to use it on a sample.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sort}

\def\mystring{}
\makeatletter\def\addstring#1{\g@addto@macro\mystring{ #1}}\makeatother

\begin{document}

Sorted Literals: \sortalpha{{Goodbye, 1}{Cruel, 2}{World, 3}}

\bigskip

\addstring{goodbye, \pageref{pg:goodbye}.} \label{pg:goodbye}
\addstring{cruel, \pageref{pg:cruel}.} \label{pg:cruel}
\addstring{world, \pageref{pg:world}.} \label{pg:world}

Collected: \texttt{\mystring}

Sorted Collected: \sortalpha{\mystring}

\end{document}
```

The output is appropriately sorted for the literals, but not for the contents of the string.  `\expandafter` before `\mystring` does not seem to do it, either.

[image: unsorted output]

I hope the magic to accomplish this on the contents of the macro is simple.  help appreciated.

PS: I admit to wanting to create my own little sorted keyword index (with simple sequential running rather than more fancy formatting) at the end of my latex file *without* having to invoke an external program like `\makeindex`.  I may also need to add a `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: In general, `\expandafter\sortalpha\expandafter{\mystring}` would be required to sort the contents of `\mystring`.  Also, your `\addstring` definition should be `\g@addto@macro\mystring{{#1}}}` to mimic your literal case input.  Finally, there seems to be an issue when doing what I say on the first pass, because `\pageref` is still not sorted out.  But once you can get the aux file written properly, what I suggest works.

Comment: ... you know, there's no magic and there's no easy way to program. Understand the code you copy-pasted properly before trying to edit it. -- Or just write your own with expl3.

Comment: Thx, Steven.  Weird problem: When the `\pageref` is to a non-existent label (as it is on the first pass), latex blocks with `! Undefined control sequence. \reserved@a ->\@nil` at the ` \expandafter\sortalpha\expandafter{\mystring}`.  I had hoped that `\pageref` would just produce the standard '??' text on the first run and the correct page number on the second run, but instead the `\expandafter` completely blocks the first run.  Easy fix?

Comment: Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111311/how-to-make-a-conditional-reference-to-a-text-label you can do `\def\chkpageref#1{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{0}{\pageref{#1}}}` and then `\addstring{goodbye, \chkpageref{pg:goodbye}.}`.

Answer (score 1):

This just summarizes Steven Segletes and Marijn's answers.  Thank you to both of you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sort}

\makeatletter
\def\mykeywords{}
\def\kwclear{\def\mykeywords{}}
\def\addkeyword#1{\g@addto@macro\mykeywords{{#1}}}
\def\chkpageref#1{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{na}{\pageref{#1}}}
\def\kw#1{\textbf{#1}\addkeyword{#1, p.\chkpageref{pg:#1}}\label{pg:#1}}
\def\kwprint{\par\textbf{Keywords: } \expandafter\sortalpha\expandafter{\mykeywords}\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\kwclear

The text is hello and \kw{goodbye}.  \kw{cruel} people are in this \kw{world}.

\bigskip

\kwprint

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

and for completeness the `sort.sty` again:

```
%% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% #1 - comparator
% #2 - token list to sort
\newcommand\sort[2]{%
        \ifstrempty{#2}
        {}% else
        {%
                \sort@begin#1{}#2\sort@s\sort@begin
        }%
}

% helpers
\def\sort@s{\sort@s}
\def\ifsort@s#1{%
        \ifx\sort@s#1%
                \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
                \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
}

% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - smallest token so far
% #4 - rest of the list
\def\sort@begin#1#2#3#4\sort@begin{%
        \ifsort@s{#4}
        {%
                \sortend{#3}%
                \sort#1{#2}%
        }% else
        {%
                \sort@go#1{#2}{#3}#4\sort@go
        }%
}

% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - smallest token so far
% #4 - token under consideration
% #5 - rest of the list
\def\sort@go#1#2#3#4#5\sort@go{%
        #1{#3}{#4}{\sort@output#1{#2}{#5}}%
}
% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - rest of the list
% #4 - smaller of the two tokens
% #5 - larger of the two tokens
\def\sort@output#1#2#3#4#5{%
        \ifsort@s{#3}
        {%
                \sortoutput{#4}%
                \sort#1{#2{#5}}%
        }% else
        {%
                \sort@begin#1{#2{#5}}{#4}#3\sort@begin
        }%
}

\def\sort@numlt#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{#1}<{#2}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@numgt#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{#1}>{#2}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@alpha#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}}<{0}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand*\sortnumlt{\sort\sort@numlt}
\newcommand*\sortnumgt{\sort\sort@numgt}
\newcommand*\sortalpha{\sort\sort@alpha}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\sortoutput[1]{#1 $\rightarrow$ }
\newcommand*\sortend[1]{#1. $\leftarrow$ }
```